# Select input default selected value not selected

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have following select input in a modal dialog:

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-3  control-label">Status</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
                              <select class="form-control" id="txtstatus" >

                                  <option  value="1" selected="selected"> En proceso </option>
                                  <option value="2"> Solucionado </option>
                                  <option value="3"> Cancelado </option>


                              </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

But it is not selected as default value.

Screenshot to demonstrate it:

[image]

EDITED: Complete modal dialog:

```
              <div id="modalcust" class="modal">

                <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Formulario de Capacitaciones</h4>
                    </div>
                    <!--modal header-->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="pad" id="infopanel"></div>
                      <div class="form-horizontal">

                        <div class="form-group"> 
                          <label class="col-sm-3  control-label">Número</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtnumero" placeholder="Número de Capacitación" readonly>
                              <input type="hidden" id="crudmethod" value="N"> 
                              <input type="hidden" id="txtid" value="0">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                           <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-3  control-label">Unidad Médica</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
                              <select class="form-control" id="txtunidad" >


                              <?php
include "../config.php";
$query=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM tb_unidades") ;
$data = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $data[] = $r;
}
$i=0;
foreach ($data as $key) {
        // add new button
    $data[$i]['button'] ;
    echo '<option value="'.$data[$i]['id_unidad'].'">'.$data[$i]['nombre_unidad'].'</option>';
    $i++;
}
$datax = array('data' => $data);
echo json_encode($datax);
?>



                              </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                           <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-3  control-label">Instrumento</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
                              <select class="form-control" id="txtinstrumento" name="txtinstrumento" >


                              <option value="">Selecciona primero la Unidad Médica</option>

                              </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group"> 
                          <label class="col-sm-3  control-label">Area</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtarea" placeholder="Area" readonly>
                              <input type="hidden" id="crudmethod" value="N"> 
                              <input type="hidden" id="txtid" value="0">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     <div class="form-group"> 
                          <label class="col-sm-3  control-label">Descripción</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtdescripcion" placeholder="Descripción de la capacitación">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                          <div class="form-group"> 
                          <label class="col-sm-3  control-label">Responsable</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
                              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="txtresponsable" placeholder="Responsable" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group"> 
                          <label class="col-sm-3  control-label">Email</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
                              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="txtemail" placeholder="Email" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group"> 
                          <label class="col-sm-3  control-label">Celular</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
                              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="txttel" placeholder="Celular">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="form-group"> 
                          <label class="col-sm-3  control-label">Tel fijo</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
                              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="txttelfijo" placeholder="Tel fijo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <div class="form-group"> <!-- Date input -->
         <label class="col-sm-3  control-label">Fecha Solicitud Capacitación</label>

         <?php 
         // Change the line below to your timezone!
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
$date = date('d-m-Y h:i:s', time());?>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input class="form-control" id="txtfechapeticion" name="txtfechapeticiom" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" type="text" value="<?php echo $date?>" readonly/>
      </div>
      </div>
                               <div class="form-group"> <!-- Date input -->
         <label class="col-sm-3  control-label">Fecha Inicio</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input class="form-control" id="txtfechareporte" name="txtfechareporte" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" type="text"/>
      </div>
      </div>
          <div class="form-group"> <!-- Date input -->
         <label class="col-sm-3  control-label">Fecha Final</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input class="form-control" id="txtfechasolucion" name="txtfechasolucion" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" type="text"/>
      </div>
      </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-3  control-label">Status</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
                              <select class="form-control" id="txtstatus" >

                                  <option  value="1" selected="selected"> En proceso </option>
                                  <option value="2"> Solucionado </option>
                                  <option value="3"> Cancelado </option>


                              </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group"> 
                          <label class="col-sm-3  control-label">Comentarios</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtcomentarios" placeholder="Comentarios">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group"> 
                          <label class="col-sm-3  control-label"></label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "   id="btnsave"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Guardar</button></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                      <!--modal footer-->
                    </div>
                    <!--modal-content-->
                  </div>
                  <!--modal-dialog modal-lg-->
                </div>
                <!--form-kantor-modal-->
              </div>
```

Comment: just mark selected instead of selected="sleected"

Comment: @JordanGeorgiadis, already tried with the same result, Thank you

Comment: Try just using selected instead of select="selected", its basically the same thing but I tried it just now and its working. If that doesn't work then try posting the mark up surrounding the form-group. It's likely something wrong outside of that block. Using your exact mark up above in my local environment, both select="selected" and just selected works.

Comment: @JoshuaMaddox, I have posted the whole modal form

Comment: Try wrapping the form with a <form> tag. Most broswers need to see the form tag for certain types of behaviour. Also, its worth mentioning that if you're using Firefox you can get some unexpected behaviour with selected="selected" because it defaults to the users' last known selection and ignores the selected attribute.

Comment: Can you give a link to sample code in JSFiddle or edit this question and insert a code snippet? It works here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option

Comment: @Chloe, I have just checked that removing the id tag inside the select, it works. Any clue?

Comment: You might have Javascript that is de-selecting the option upon page load. Eventually if you want it to submit, you'll have to give the `<select>` a name attribute. Try to create a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) link with the code showing it happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<option  value="1" selected>`